# Python mechanize cannot find link

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm using this code to print links in a web page

```
wb = mechanize.Browser()
wb.open("https://example.com")

print wb.response().read()
for link in wb.links():
     print "aa->"
```

The response is this:

```
...
    <a href=/Router/moneyReload.web;JSESSIONID=2C832E9B3DB0EE7162D7434FC352B85E.coreAR02>Recarga De Saldo</a><br><a href=/Router/roamingMoneyReload.web;JSESSIONID=2C832E9B3DB0EE7162D7434FC352B85E.coreAR02>Recarga en Roaming</a><br><a href=/Router/lastOperatorSale.web;JSESSIONID=2C832E9B3DB0EE7162D7434FC352B85E.coreAR02>Ultima Recarga</a><br><a href=/Router/LastSubscriberTopUpPerform.web;JSESSIONID=2C832E9B3DB0EE7162D7434FC352B85E.coreAR02>Consulta de Recarga</a><br><a href=/Router/stockReportCreditLimit.web;JSESSIONID=2C832E9B3DB0EE7162D7434FC352B85E.coreAR02>Informe de Ventas</a><br><a href=/Router/stockReport.web;JSESSIONID=2C832E9B3DB0EE7162D7434FC352B85E.coreAR02>Informe de Saldo Disponible</a><br><a href=/Router/dealerCloseBatch.web;JSESSIONID=2C832E9B3DB0EE7162D7434FC352B85E.coreAR02>Cierre de Turno</a><br><a href=/Router/ChangePointOfSalePin.web;JSESSIONID=2C832E9B3DB0EE7162D7434FC352B85E.coreAR02>Cambiar PIN</a><br><a href=/Router/activePortfolioQuery.web;JSESSIONID=2C832E9B3DB0EE7162D7434FC352B85E.coreAR02>Consulta Portfolio</a><br></body></html>
```

As you can see, there are some links in there, but I'm not getting any links in the 'for'

Maybe because they have'nt any quotes in href attribute. But in this case how can I read them?

thanks

Comment: what about using `urlopen` and some `regex` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't print the links while iterating over them.

This works:

```
wb = mechanize.Browser()
wb.open("https://example.com")

for link in wb.links():
    print link
```

Comment: no I know, I'm just printing "aa>" to check it enters the for. Anyway, I tried your solution and still not workinkg

Comment: No. I was able to solve it by using the next constructor:

`wb=mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())`

I think this allows mechanize to search in malformed html. I've also  tried with BeautifulSoup with success